# Java Regular expression - Pattern matching on a pipe-delimited string

Tags: java, regex

This is pretty basic, but I'm not sure what I'm missing. I'm trying to do a pattern match on a pipe-delimited string, to ensure that I can process it accurately (checking a pre-condition).

Input strings will be of the form:
IMAGE|{HEIGHT}|{WIDTH}|{ASPECTRATIO}
Example:
IMAGE|1080|1920|16x9

I'm trying to validate if the string is in this format with the regular expression:

`IMAGE\\|[0-9]?\\|[0-9]?\\|[0-9]?x[0-9]?"`

But:

```
String pattern = "IMAGE\\|[0-9]?\\|[0-9]?\\|[0-9]?x[0-9]?";
System.out.println("IMAGE|1080|1920|16x9".matches(pattern));
```

returns false. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you mean to use `+` to indicate one or more of where you're using `?` to indicate 0 or 1 of.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. Sigh! Pretty basic, but needed a second pair of eyes. Cheers.

Comment: You're most welcome, @user1452030 - glad to help and thanks for confirming the fix worked. Please accept my answer?

Comment: Done. Couldn't accept it back then because you resolved it faster than StackOverflow could handle ;)

Comment: *lol* Fascinating! Interesting to know that can happen - thank you.